# Changing Canvas Lines, or, An Adjusting Line Between Two Points

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Is it possible to change a line drawn to the canvas? So, if a line is drawn with:

```
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.lineWidth="2";
    ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(42, 155, 128, 0.9)"; 
    ctx.moveTo(linkX,linkY);
    ctx.lineTo(postX,postY);
    ctx.stroke();
```

Then later, as the mouse moves, `postX` and `postY` change positions and the path gets updated. I'm trying to draw a line between two points that move with the mouse on hover.

So far I've drawn three lines which I want to update the lineTo positions of, but have no way of selecting them. If this was just css it'd be something like:

```
$link.on('mousemove', function(e){
    $post.css({
        left: mouse.x,
        top: mouse.y
    });
 });
```

How can I do this kind of thing with canvas elements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas isn't smart. It wont remember your line as an object. Whenevet you draw a line canvas will forget it. You will need to keep track of the coordinates of the shapes(line) you have drawn on canvas. And then create a feel of line being moved by clearing existing line and redrawing it on new positions.

Comment: How do you mean Naeem? I wouldn't be able to clear the canvas and draw a line again on mousemove as it would be happening constant, that would be super intensive wouldn't it? Would you approach this differently? Cheers.

Comment: On further inspection/testing, somehow, it seems to be working out :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out if I add the drawing part to be a part of the mousemove event, it works. Not sure if it's the best way to do it but heyho.

```
    $link.on('mousemove', function(e){
      ctx.beginPath(); 
      ctx.lineWidth="2";
      ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(42, 155, 128, 0.9)"; 
      ctx.moveTo(linkX,linkY);
      ctx.lineTo(postX,postY);
      ctx.stroke();
    });
```